# Changing URL onClick in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, window.location

In my project I have a `TabComponent` which displays 3 tabs: home, popular, all.

Now, I am using `context` of react to maintain:

1. `activetab` which stores current tab.
2. `toggleTab` method which changes `activetab` using `setState`.

**TabComponent**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Context from '../../provider'
import {Nav, NavItem, NavLink} from 'reactstrap'
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'
import classnames from 'classnames'

export default class TabComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Context.Consumer>
                {context => (
                    <Nav tabs color='primary'>
                        <NavItem>
                            <NavLink
                                className={classnames({ active: context.activeTab === '1' })}
                                onClick={() =>{context.toggleTab('1')}}
                            >
                            Home
                            </NavLink>
                        </NavItem>
                        <NavItem>
                            <NavLink
                                className={classnames({ active: context.activeTab === '2' })}
                                onClick={() => {context.toggleTab('2')}}
                            >
                            Popular
                            </NavLink>
                        </NavItem>
                        <NavItem>
                            <NavLink
                                className={classnames({ active: context.activeTab === '3' })}
                                onClick={() => {context.toggleTab('3')}}
                            >
                            All
                            </NavLink>
                        </NavItem>                
                    </Nav>
                )}
            </Context.Consumer>
        )
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is, `onClick` should also change the URL.

- For tab 1, the url should be `\home\`
- For tab 2, the url should be `\popular\`
- For tab 3, the url should be `\all\`

---

Using `this.props.history` in the `onClick` method is not working with `export default withRouter(TabComponent)`.

```
<NavLink
    className={classnames({ active: context.activeTab === '1' })}
    onClick={() =>{
        context.toggleTab('1');
        this.props.history('/home/');
    }}
>
```

**Error**:

> You should not use `<Route>` or `withRouter()` outside a `<Router>`

---

`window.location` in `onClick`:

```
<NavLink
    className={classnames({ active: context.activeTab === '1' })}
    onClick={() =>{
        context.toggleTab('1');
        window.location = '/home/';
    }}
>
```

This actually works but the behaviour is not good.

Clicking the tab does the following:

1. It Changes the content of body using `context.toggleTab`.
2. Then it changes the URL using `window.location`.
3. Since, the URL changed, the page is getting reloaded.

The problem here is the **content is already loaded in the 1st step**. Using `window.location` changes the URL but also **re-loads** the page which is not required. It there a way to do skip the 3rd step or is that any other method which **just** changes the URL?

Comment: If you are using react-router , you can use this.props.history(url). Else you can use window.location = url.

Comment: I am unsure on where to write `this.props.history(url)`!!

Comment: You can either write it in your onClick function or in the toggle function. Both would work i guess

Comment: I am getting error if i do that, I have updated my question.

Comment: That is because TabComponent is not rendered by <Route>. So you can use window.location = url instead of this.props.history

Comment: How do I solve the problem that I stated in the update?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174484/discussion-between-ragul-parani-and-sreekar-mouli).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `TabComponent` does not have access to the React Router `history` route prop because it's probably not used as a `component` given to a `Route`.

You could use [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter) on your `TabComponent` to get access to the [route props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/route-props).

```
class TabComponent extends Component {
    render() {
      // ...
    }
}

export default withRouter(TabComponent);
```

You also must make sure that you have a [`Router`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter) component at the top of your app.

**Example**

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        {/* ... */}
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That did do the trick, I didn't quite understand why we need to have a `BrowserRouter` at top level?

Comment: @SreekarMouli `withRouter` uses values from the context supplied by the `Router` component, so if a component using the `withRouter` HOC is rendered outside of the Router, it cannot get the proper information it needs.