# Reactjs - modifying State and changing URL onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url

I am trying to change the `state` and **URL** `onChange` on a `<Input type='select'>`. 
(I am using reactstrap)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {
    Input,
} from 'reactstrap'

export default class NewPostComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            selected: '',
        }
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            selected: event.target.value,
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Input type='select' onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}>
                <option>option 1</option>
                <option>option 2</option>
                <option>option 3</option>
                <option>option 4</option>
            </Input>
        )
    }
}
```

I am changing the `state` but the problem comes at changing the **URL**. I have tried `props.history.push` but in `handleChange` as follows:

```
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        selected: event.target.value,
    })
    this.props.history.push(`/${this.state.selected}/new/`)
}
```

This is the ERROR that I am getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

`console.log(this.props.history)` is `undefined`.

I just need a way to change **URL** after `setState` occurs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `history` prop is only passed to the components that are given to `Route` components.

```
{/* The Login component will get the history prop */}
<Route path="/login" component={Login} />
```

You could use [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) if you want the [route props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props) in a component that is not directly used for a `Route`.

Since `setState` is asynchronous, you can push to the `history` in the callback to `setState` to make sure the state has changed before you change the url.

```
class NewPostComponent extends Component {
    state = {
        selected: ''
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            selected: event.target.value,
        }, () => {
            this.props.history.push(`/${this.state.selected}/new/`)
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Input type='select' onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}>
                <option>option 1</option>
                <option>option 2</option>
                <option>option 3</option>
                <option>option 4</option>
            </Input>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(NewPostComponent)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. That really solved a lot of other probs too. I also want `props.history.push` to happen only after `setState` has occured.

Comment: Can the same technique be applied on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51205809/8208804) question?

Comment: @SreekarMouli I have never tried `withRouter(NavLink);` but it might work, yes.

Comment: I am updating that post, pls take a look at that thanks